# Maven plugin support for existing Eclipse web app

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications

I have an existing dynamic web app (web service) project written using Eclipse Helios. I now have need (per client request) to make this a "Maven project". Using the m2eclipse plugin I attempted to "add Maven support" via the project's Maven context menu. The result of having done this is a pom.xml file was added to the project (I don't know if anything else changed) however, this pom doesn't appear to have enough data embedded to be useful in describing the project or it's dependencies. Having zero experience with Maven I don't really know what to expect.

Is this the correct (or an acceptable) practice for adding Maven to an existing project? I see an overload of information online about Maven but most everything seems to want to start from a new Maven project; which also would be okay if I knew which archetype to start from and how to go about re-creating a web service from a Maven project.

Sorry for the run-on, stream of consciousness above, I'm not sure what question(s) to ask. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you will have to learn how maven works. There is a good introduction book made by sonatype.

Here are some of the steps you will have to do :

1. Configure Sources, resources and tests folders
2. Configure Libraries dependencies : adding right dependencies to your pom, adding public repositories to download the dependencies
3. Define package type
4. ...

Comment: thanks florian for this useless bit of info and for the down vote preventing others from contributing something helpful

Comment: Sorry but : 1) I didn't vote you down, it was someone else 2) If you read just a little bit about maven, you would have known that my answer was anything but useless

Comment: Florian is right. If you want to use a new technique, then you obviously have to learn how to use it. Florian gave you some important points where to look. And it is clear, that the pom is empty, because M2Eclipse can't guess, which dependencies you need, and that the groupids, artifactids and versions of the dependencies are. You have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

teps .

1. Add [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)
2. (Very recommended is to convert to [standard maven
   folder layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html))
3. try using maven from command line like `mvn
   package` to see if it work.
4. Only after success change Eclipse files (.project .classpath)